# is there a way to control a pc program by python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, automation, spotify, ui-automation

If I want to be specific about what I'm trying to do that's this: when my windows start, Spotify starts with it so I'm trying to create a script which can autofill the username and password (prefer password because I have an account) and hit the login box. **like how Selenium works for web browsers**. I've seen programs that record mouse and keyboard tasks, but they don't work accurately like sometimes they click somewhere else and some other issues.

Comment: pywinauto i guess... is one package that should work ...

Answer (score 1):

You can try [AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/).

It's a automation scripting language for Windows. All you need to do is write simple scripts like `python` and click it to run.

The script will like this:

```
^j::
Run, spotify.exe
Send, send your keys here
SendInput, send input here
return
```

when you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd> ,it will start spotify.exe and send some keys or input to Spotify. The script here is just an example, you need to read the docs for more info.